# django html form that is showing error this field is required

Tags: django

the post method is not getting the username record.  the get method is working fine but html form is showing the following error:

> This field is required

```
<h2>Users</h2>

<ul>
<form method="post" action=""><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='8gQo0iGRTDE7kayhFJqj2fOt7UkejlkG' />

        <li>
        <input type="text" value= mayur><br>
        <input type="submit" value="follow" />
        </li>

        <li>
        <input type="text" value= mayurnitrr><br>
        <input type="submit" value="follow" />
        </li>

        <li>
        <input type="text" value= lokesh><br>
        <input type="submit" value="follow" />
        </li>

</form>
</ul>

<p align="center"><a href="/home/">Back</a></p>
```

Comment: Why form action is empty? You should post to a url.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you handle these but none of your inputs have a name parameter which you need to provide

```
<input type="text" name="somethingdescriptive" value="lokesh"><br>
```

`request.POST` should now contain the key "somethingdescriptive"